# Changing last li hover in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting together a nav bar and found a nice script to allow a li to keep in its 'hover' state while a 2nd level menu is displayed. In my last li I have a search bar and would like to remove the hover. Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul#topnav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
        $(this).css({ 'background' : '#7bbdc2 '}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
        $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav 
    } , 
    function() { //on hover out...
        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
        $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [exclude an element](http://api.jquery.com/not/) from the selector. Do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul#topnav li").not('li:last').hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
        $(this).css({ 'background' : '#7bbdc2 '}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
        $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav 
    } , 
    function() { //on hover out...
        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
        $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: this reads even cleaner than my approach with the "attribute-not-equal" selector. but NOTE: the argument that this code will fail as soon as you add another LI element after the search is still valid. You should select (filter out) the search by element ID and not via the "last" selector..

Answer (score 3):

didn't test my suggestion. try this:

```
$("ul#topnav li:last-child").hover(nil);
```

following your existing code. your code adds the hover element to all `li` elements in #topnav, so after this find the last one and remove the hover.

Note: this is not the best solution because when you add some new `li` element below the search you will end up with the wrong result.
better give the search `li` element its own unique identifier and remove the hover on this element:

```
$("ul#topnav li#search").hover(nil);
```

EDIT:

or even better - use the attribute not equal selector right from the beginning..

instead of:

```
$("ul#topnav li").hover(function() {
  // ...
```

give your search `li` the `id` "search" and do this:

```
$('ul#topnav li[id!="search"]').hover(function() {
  // ...
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: Thanks for this, tried the 2nd line of code which made good sense (I already had the li classed as 'search') yet no joy..... I just added your line of code to my script,  $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
 $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    $("ul#topnav li#search").hover(nil);

});
 
});
</script>

Comment: @valleys-boy: a class is not the same as an ID.. the id is unique while a class is not. the id identifies a specific element, a class is used to group several elements together. if you have a class and use the id selector it will not work.